# Fast Get method in VBA then objHttp.Send ""

Tags: vba, security, excel-2010

TI am creating a VBA script in excel 2010 that goes over vuln data looking for this regex patter `MS[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]`, then does the following:

```
objHttp.Open "GET", "http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/" & MS, False
objHttp.Send ""
```

Then I parse out the severity from the html.

The issue is that I have over 200,000 lines of vulns and each get request take about 1-3 secs. so the math adds up to about 55.55 hrs worstcase scenario. Is there a faster way to associate a MS vuln to the severity.

Comment: Not do it in Excel and do the requests in parallel

Comment: Do you actually have >200k *distinct* values for `MS` ?

Comment: No, which is a valid point. I can start creating a local database with ms vulns and severity and reference that prior to making the get request.